# How to connect to PPTP server in Android programmatically?

Tags: java, android, android-webview, pptp

I have set up [pptpd](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?name=pptpd) on Ubuntu.

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to connect to my [PPTP](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PPTP_server) server using Android code.

My goal is to make a WebView Android application that can connect automatically to my PPTP server that acts as a VPN.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you're asking? What have you tried so far and what goes wrong with it?

Comment: i don't know how to make my app to connect to my pptpd server

in what section, where i must enter:
server ip address
login
pass

in android studio to make my apps can connect to my pptpd vps

Comment: hello, anybody here????

Comment: Did anybody find some solution ?